# Change XCode default from relative to XCode folder?

Tags: xcode

I'm really really tired of other users having project errors because XCode's default class reference type is "relative to XCode folder." I know you can change it to "Relative to Enclosing Group," which is what our project is, but anytime someone creates a new classfile and forgets to change the reference type afterwards (frequently) or adds and file and forgets to change the reference type (also frequently), users who update from SVN see red file errors, even though it exists in the correct folder - just because the xcodeproj file links to it stupidly.

Is there any way to change the default? I've been looking through the preferences and can't find anything. It seems there must be ways to make XCode work better for situations other than single-user projects. I am incredibly unimpressed with its source control management, and I'm hoping maybe that's because I haven't been able to find some options. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good question. In my case "Relative to Enclosing Group" is the default, and I don't remember changing this setting anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this is to map my groups to the source file hierarchy and make sure that everything is initially set up as "Relative to Enclosing Group". In this case Xcode seems to do the right thing when you add more files or folders to the hierarchy, i.e. it maintains the "Relative to Enclosing Group" setting wherever it can.

For more info try asking on the [xcode-users mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/xcode-users).

Comment: Even though that isn't the exact answer, it does solve the problem if you're careful at the beginning. Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this some time as well, yet the answer is simple:

Don't store your projects in the developer folder. Inside the developer folder everything defaults to relative to XCode Folder, while outside it's to enclosing group.

Hope it helps